# Pushing multiple folders to Git

Tags: git, github

I am quite new to github. I worked on a project which has multiple folders. Now when I try to push the local repo to github, only the files in the root are getting pushed (Not the files inside folders).

I am following these commands

```
git add .
git commit -m "message"
git push -u origin master
```

Can someone point out the actual commands

**EDIT:** Sample Folder Structure

```
root
/Folder1/File1.txt
/Folder1/File2.txt
/Folder1/File3.txt
/Folder1/SubFolder1/File.txt
/Folder2/File1.txt
/Folder2/File2.txt
/Folder2/File3.txt
/Folder3/SubFolder1/File.txt
/README
/index.php
```

Comment: That is not possible since you are using `git add .`. Give sample folder structure and output of `git status`

Comment: Can you add the output of git status before and after you run the git add, like this... `git status` `git add .` `git status` ?

Comment: Also to add to the other guys - does git push give an error?

Comment: Does the result of commit show the files inside the sub directories?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try using `git add -A`. This should add everything including those files that are untracked.

Answer (score -1):

delete the old .git
then do **git init**
then **git add -A**
if this didnt work check .gitignore by doing **git status --ignore**